# Common base class for ios view controllers using storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to use a base class `MyBaseViewController` that's a subclass of `UIViewController` for every view controller that I'll use in my app, so that I could have some things set up in that base controllers for convenience.

I created a storyboard with a `UITableViewController` object in it, and I'm writing a custom controller class `MyTableViewController` for it.

I wanted `MyTableViewController` to subclass `MyBaseViewController` and implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` for it to work properly with a table view, but when I tried to set the class for the `UITableViewController` object in my storyboard, it doesn't allow me to select the custom class I wrote.

I assume this is because the storyboard wants me to use a class that's a sub class of `UITableViewController`?

Is there a way to get this to work without changing `MyTableViewController`'s inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no. `UITableViewController`'s ancestry is already defined. It inherits directly from UIViewController. You can't insert a new ancestor after the fact.

Objective-C doesn't have multiple inheritance, which would make this easy.

You could define your own subclass of `UIViewController` that implements the table view delegate and data source methods, and use that instead of a `UITableViewController` as the base class for your table view, but some things won't work unless the host of your table view is a `UITableViewController`.

If you don't need to add instance variables to your view controllers or override existing methods you might be able to define a category of UIController (UIViewController+MyMethods).

You might also create a set of methods that you add to both a custom subclass of UIViewController and `UITableViewController`. If you put your extra source code into a separate source file you could `#include` that source file in the body of your `MyViewController.m`. and your `MyTableViewController.m` files:

You might have a file ExtraVCMethods.m:

```
- (void) methodOne
{
  //code
}

- (void) methodTwo
{
  //code
}
```

And then in your MyViewController.m:

```
@implementation MyViewController

#include "ExtraVCMethods.m"

@end
```

And in your MyTableViewController.m:

```
@implementation MyTableViewController

#include "ExtraVCMethods.m"

@end
```

(Note that I am #including a .m file, not a .h file, and the `#include` goes inside the implementation, which is unusual.)

The `#include` would cause the compiler to insert the same source in the body of both classes. That way if you change the source for your extra methods you don't have to change it in 2 places.

Note that with the above approach you turn off the target membership checkbox for your ExtraVCMethods.m file. You don't want that compiled separately - just pasted into your other source files by the precompiler.

Comment: I see. What should I do if I do want to inherit instance variables though? I just hope that the UITableViewController in my storyboard could work with a custom class that's not an instanceof `UITableViewController`.

Also you mentioned something just wouldn't work unless the host is a `UITableViewController`, what are these?

Comment: Things like static table views and cell templates assume that the containing view controller is a UITableViewController. I don't have an exhaustive list. I've just found things that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.  Objective C doesn't support multiple inheritance.

I don't know what kind of defaults you're setting up in `MyBaseViewController` but if you moved them to an extension of `UIViewController` you could then have `MyTableViewController` and `MyBaseViewController` both call the same extension methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what extensions are... Are they categories? I guess the thing with categories is just that they don't allow instance variables.

Comment: @a283626086 yes, the same as a category.  And yes that is a problem, but if you want to achieve what you're talking about it's really the only way.

Comment: Ahh I see. I guess I'll have to figure something out :\ Thanks!

Comment: @a283626086 yeah, sorry.  But if you'd like to do some runtime hacking and add properties in a category, use this: http://kaspermunck.github.io/2012/11/adding-properties-to-objective-c-categories/

Comment: Oh It's all good. I've decided to make a compromise and change what I had in the storyboard into a UIViewController and work on that instead. Thanks for the link! I'll keep that in mind in case I'll need to do that in the future.